# Verifying equivalence relation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

Define $x$~$y$ if $xy$ are the sum of $2^n$ squares in a field $K$. Is this an equivalence relation? The only non-trivial thing to verify is transitivity, and I have no clues of whether it is true or not, let alone proving it or providing a counter-example. Could somebody give a hint? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I've verified it in the case of $n=1$ using complex number and $n=2$ using quaternion, but don't know how to continue. I think the difficulty is to define multiplication in $2^n$-dimension vector space over K.

Comment: Is $n$ here fixed, or is it for any positive integer $n$?

Comment: Of course for any integer n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You'll want to use [Pfister's Theorem](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/pfister.pdf):
In any field, the set of sums of $2^n$ squares is closed under multiplication.

**Full Solution:**

> Then if $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$, $xy$ and $yz$ are sums of $2^n$ squares, but then
>  $xy^2z$ is a sum of $2^n$ squares by Pfister's theorem. Dividing by $y^2$, we see $xz$ is a sum of 2^n squares, so $x\sim z$.

Comment: Knowing Pfister's Theorem makes this problem trivial.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just haven't encountered it before.

Comment: @YuiToCheng it's certainly not one of the more common theorems. I don't think wikipedia even has a page for it. I wouldn't have known about it except for a course on quadratic forms. I'm pretty sure that's what you're supposed to use though, since it's equivalent to your problem. That or you're supposed to essentially reprove it.

Comment: I don't think I can come up with such an elegant way to prove the Pfister Theorem. Your link is nice!